# how to add http header such as basic auth when retry the message from the JMS store using schedulemessageforwardprocessor?

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using the new feature Message store and processor from ESB 4 for the reliable delivery.

The endpoint service requires basic auth (a http Authorization header) which I added during the in sequence through a property with scope of "transport".

the endpoint is defined as:
    
    
        
        -1
        1.0

It works when end point up running, the message will be sent with auth header from in sequence.
when the end point is down, the message will be saved to JMS message store.
The problem is when the message being retried by the ScheduleMessageForwardingProcessor, I don't know where/how to add the auth header, and without the auth header all the retry message will fail even when the endpoint is up again.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is a limitation in WSO2 ESB Message Processors. We have added these features in the trunk ESB and they will be available in the next public release of WSO2 ESB.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Should I look at the http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/trunk/java/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processors/forward/BlockingMessageSender.java? How to add http header from MessageContext?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Has this been incorporated in newer ESB version? Currently using ESB 4.9